# Entity Framework: One way SaveChanges() works, the other way it does not. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I do this, context.SaveChanges() works fine:

```
List<Messages> DbChangedMessages = context.Messages
                    .Where(m => m.Status == 0)
                    .OrderBy(m => m.insertdate)
                    .Take(maxNumberOfMessages)
                    .ToList();

//look for messages that point to invalid template
List<Messages> invalidMessages = (from m in DbChangedMessages
                                 join t in context.Templates on m.templateId equals t.id
                                 where m.Status == 0 && t.invalid == true
                                 select m)
                                 .ToList();

if (invalidMessages.Count > 0)
{
    //set Status=11 for all messages that have Status=0 and point to an invalid template
    invalidMessages.ForEach(m => m.Status = 11);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The new Status 11 is written to the database.
But if I move the first query to a static function returning the List like this, SaveChanges() does not work (the rest is unchanged).

```
List<Messages> DbChangedMessages = MessageMethods.GetChangedMessages(maxNumberOfMessages);

//look for messages that point to invalid template
List<Messages> invalidMessages = (from m in DbChangedMessages
                                 join t in context.Templates on m.templateId equals t.id
                                 where m.Status == 0 && t.invalid == true
                                 select m)
                                 .ToList();

if (invalidMessages.Count > 0)
{
    //set Status=11 for all messages that have Status=0 and point to an invalid template
    invalidMessages.ForEach(m => m.Status = 11);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Why?

Comment: You don't pass your context to your static method... how would it know to use your context? Please post a [mcve], we are basically guessing here.

Comment: why static? probably in the static method the context is different from the context on which you call SaveChanges considering that it is not passed as parameter

Comment: its as nvoigt describes, you need to make sure the entities are attracted in the right state and connected to the right/same context.

Comment: Why would you even consider moving a dbcontext call to static. please reconsider your architecture

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I had two different dbcontext instances to the same db, one in the calling method and one in the static class. I removed the one in the static class and pass the outer dbcontext to MessageMethods.GetChangedMessages() and now it works (=db gets updated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change tracking that Entity Framework does is done by the DbContext itself. The MessageMethods.GetChangedMessages method is using a different DbContext than the method that calls it, so the changes aren't tracked properly. You could either pass in the context to the GetChangedMessages method or you could attach the entities to the context as you need to:

```
invalidMessages.ForEach(m => 
{
    m.Status = 11;
    context.Messages.Attach(m);
});
```